# Amazon S3 or DynamoDB

Tags: android, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking to use the Amazon Web Services (S3 and DynamoDB). Currently I am creating an Android App that would otherwise require me to store User Information for registration/log in, and User generated content such as pictures, strings of sorts, dates and times.. etc.

Has anyone had any experience with these 2 services and which on would be ideal for my current application. I believe the Amazon S3 is just primarily just to store files/images and I don't believe it calls for multiple user interaction but I may be missing something.

Any advice would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, neither of them will be "the" (single) solution.  You very well might use both, although you should probably also consider [RDS against DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#When_should_I_use_Amazon_DynamoDB_vs_a_relational_database_engine_on_Amazon_RDS_or_Amazon_EC2) since DynamoDB is a database, but not a relational database, and is only indexed on the primary key.

From the [DynamoDB FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/):

> **Q: When should I use Amazon DynamoDB vs Amazon S3?**
>
> Amazon DynamoDB stores structured data, indexed by primary key, and allows low latency read and write access to items ranging from 1 byte up to 64KB. Amazon S3 stores unstructured blobs and suited for storing large objects up to 5 TB. In order to optimize your costs across AWS services, large objects or infrequently accessed data sets should be stored in Amazon S3, while smaller data elements or file pointers (possibly to Amazon S3 objects) are best saved in Amazon DynamoDB.
>
> <sup>— http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#When_should_I_use_Amazon_DynamoDB_vs_Amazon_S3</sup>

Comment: From what I understand though, looking at the compatibility of the AWS SDK for android there isn't much supported for Amazon RDS.

I would ultimately like for my users to be able to build a "friends" list and be able to share content between each other. I think that a  RDS would also provide a little more flexibility as I introduce more  features. However, I am not sure how to interface between an Android Mobile App and the Web Services. They refer to the Android Apps as Web Applications, but I do not have an online presence as of yet. Maybe I am confused on Terminology.

What do you think?

Comment: Oh, I would never have the app itself talk to RDS and probably not DynamoDB either... better, imho, to have the app talk to your "web" (application) server using HTTPS on a REST-ish interface that you design and develop in any of several suitable languages and have your web server handle interactions with the back-end services... your server mediating all of the interaction among the app users.

Comment: I see. So I would be looking to involve a server "layer" say using Amazon EC2 to interface with the DB I choose and have the App itself communicate with the server.

The example they show is an Elastic Load Balancer that I believe takes all the requests from the application and spreads it along the  EC2 server layer which than communicates with the Database Layer.

Comment: Exactly.  Start with one "application server" behind an ELB and scale it up later as traffic demands.  The application server mediates access to all other resources except possibly S3, where you might have some requests go directly from the client to S3 and others access S3 resources via the application server... one of the major advantage in my mind is that the App itself never gets access to any credentials that could be used to access your other AWS resources and breach your security... to design it otherwise seems like a disaster waiting to happen, in my opinion.

Comment: Right. I am so new to Android Developement and the Amazon AWS that I it is tough to put the pieces together. I have tried to figure out how to "link" each service together but I am not sure what I am missing. I feel like I can create all these components and yet have no clue how to get them to work in conjunction with one another.